# How to detect mic mute or unmute state in chrome browser on Chromebook device

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chromebook

This is the code to detect the mic mute. `stream.getAudioTracks()[0].muted` this code doesn't change the mic to muted state.

**Issue:**

The Below code doesn't detect the mic mute or unmute/state on the chrome browser on a Chromebook device.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
  .then(stream => {
    console.log("MediaStreamTrack muted:", stream.getAudioTracks()[0].muted);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: You may try:

    stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled.

Comment: @TheKNVB enabled and disabled will mute and unmute, but I want to detect if the mic is in a mute state or not

Comment: Just curious: why is this question specific to "chromebook"? This shouldn't work for all OSs, right? And I am also wondering whether is a way to do this.